# Apply the proto file to the raw protobuf data doesn't get the right DateTime value?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

The following raw protobuf data

```
[
    {"1":"ABC"},
    {"2":[{"1":1510839580}]},
    {"3":1327}
]
```

is generated from the follow C# class. The project uses protobuf-net (https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net). The second field LastLoaded has the date time of current data time.

```
 [ProtoContract]
 public class DatasetStatus
 {
     [ProtoMember(1)]
     public string Dataset { get; set; }

     [ProtoMember(2)]
     public DateTime? LastLoaded { get; set; } // Need to be decoded

     [ProtoMember(3)]
     public int LoadedRecordCount { get; set; }
 }
```

I tried to decode the raw proto data to readable data.

The following proto file is used to decode to the raw data:

```
 syntax = "proto3";

 import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

 message DatasetStatus {
     string Dataset = 1;
     google.protobuf.Timestamp LastLoaded = 2;
     int32 LoadedRecordCount = 3;
 }
```

And it got the following string. How to convert the seconds/nanos to date time?

```
{
    "Dataset":"ABC",
    "LastLoaded":{"seconds":"33673825011733788","nanos":5},
    "LoadedRecordCount":1327
}
```

I tried the following code

```
var epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0 , 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dt = epochStart.AddSeconds(1510839580);
// dt is 2017-11-16 13:39:40Z
```

However, `dt` got the value of 2017-11-16 13:39:40Z instead of a date in May 2023?